# change text of authors name for citations in vitae R package

Tags: templates, latex, r-markdown

I am slowly getting a hang of the [`vitae`](https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae) R-package which incorporates `LaTeX` and `R Markdown` into templates for CVs and resumes. In the templates, a `.bib` files can be used to list out publications. I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to change the text of a specific author in the list in the output. For instance in a list of three authors:

author 1, author 2 and author 3, Year, Title, etc. to

author 1, **author 2** and author 3, Year, Title, etc.

Comment: This question has been answered here. I can't mark it as a duplicate because it's not SO. I think this modification need you to use fully Latex, and maybe use `Sweave` files over `Markdown`. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography

Answer (score 2):

I guess you were using `vitae::bibliography_entries("*.bib")`, not the function `vitae::detailed_entries()` for your publications, right? If so, the simplest (dirty) way is to put `keep_tex: true` in the YAML, so after Kniting your `*.Rmd` file you'll get a `*.tex` file (let's name it `cv.tex`). Then run the code below:

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
readr::read_lines("cv.tex") %>% 
  str_replace_all("Your Name", "\\\\textbf{Your Name}") %>% 
  readr::write_lines("cv_bold_name.tex")
```

In the `cv_bold_name.tex` file, you'll find "Your Name" is bold by the code: `\textbf{Your Name}`. Then compile `cv_bold_name.tex` in Latex, for example in my case I compile it in TeXstudio, you'll get the bold name you want.